# Greek: indirect discourse / sequence of moods after κελεύω etc.?

Tags: greek, syntax

I'm wondering about the proper Greek translation of a sentence like:

> He ordered me to do whatever I wanted.

This sentence has an indefinite relative clause (*whatever I wanted*) after a verb of ordering in a past tense (*ordered*). What verb form would be used for the subordinate clause?

I'm asking specifically about the reading in which "whatever I wanted" is the *general* type of indefinite relative clause, not an "open/simple/particular" type. That is, the reported order is "Whatever you might want from here on out, do that", rather than "Whatever it is you want right now, do that". General indefinites use subjunctive with ἄν in the present, optative in the past.

Since this sentence is about the past, I'm pretty sure the optative is correct:

1. ἐκέλευσέ με ποιεῖν ὅτι βουλοίμην.

But what about the subjunctive?

2. ἐκέλευσέ με ποιεῖν ὅτι ἂν βούλωμαι.

It seems this would be correct if the verb κελεύω can be used as introducing indirect discourse, because in indirect discourse, there's the option of retaining the original tense and mood for "vividness", rather than applying sequence of moods. In this case, the original would be ποίει ὅτι ἂν βούλῃ, so can we keep the subjunctive with ἄν?

I can't figure out whether verbs of ordering that take an infinitive, like κελεύω, can introduce the type of construction where sequence of moods is applicable. I haven't found anything relevant in Goodwin, and Smyth (1998a) is unhelpful:

> Some verbs, as κελεύω, which might be held to introduce indirect discourse, are classed under verbs of will or desire, because, like these verbs, they do not regularly take the future infinitive; and because, unlike verbs of saying and thinking (which admit all the tenses of the infinitive) they introduce infinitives which do not show differences of time.

OK, but does that mean that, other than taking a present/aorist infinitive rather than a future infinitive, these verbs act like those that introduce indirect discourse, and therefore that sequence of moods should be applicable in sentences like the above?

Comment: As far as I understand, only the infinitive serving as the object clause is treated differently. Any subordinate clauses dependent on the infinitive should follow the normal rules. But I can't cite anything authoritative on this point.